# Trouble adding values from different ranges in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, lookup

I have a fairly unique problem I am having trouble with.

Essentially, I need to fix column U on Sheet 1. Ignore stuff out of the tables, as most of that is stuff I either will hide but reference, or testing stuff.

Here is my spreadsheet so far.

Sheet 1:[image: Sheet 1]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9AF.png)

Sheet 2:
[image: Sheet 2]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC25v.png)

Sheet 3:
[image: Sheet 3]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GKJM.png)

So, essentially I need every cell in column U to work out the tax for the coming up payday.

If the tax code letter (sheet 3) is BR, tax is calculated at 20% of everything no matter what.
Otherwise, if it is anything else, it takes the Tax number (sheet 3), timeses it by 10, and takes it away from annual salary value (sheet 3).

This tax is then applied to tax for the currently worked month. It applies this tax to the gross figure in column T on the same row.

The tricky part is the overtime. The tax is easy, as this is always charged at 20% of the whole lot. But the overtime is a month late, so it needs to look at the overtime gross from last month and work that out, then add the amount of tax charged for  current working month, along with total tax paid on overtime worked last month.

Finally, this all needs to be wrapped in an if statements... is cell in column T same row = "", then this cell = ""... otherwise continue with the calcs. Feel free to reference columns AA and AB in sheet 1 as they are staying. anything else you see not in a table is going.

Comment: Upload your third sheet somewhere in Internet and post link here in comments - someone with enough reputation will put it to your question.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. The third image is here: http://i.imgur.com/sqZQxKw.png